# I am trying to set maxFileSize but it is not honored

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I am developing an application utilizing JHipster. I have added the following to my application-dev.yml file:

```
spring:

    profiles:
        active: dev

    multipart:
        maxFileSize: -1
```

But I am still getting an error when I try to try to upload a file > 1MB:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (20663006) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
```

What am I missing? It seems this should be pretty straight forward.

**Update 1**

I un-nested it from `spring` config as suggested by Andy, but still got the error. Updated yml file:

```
server:
    port: 8080

multipart:
        maxFileSize: -1

spring:

    profiles:
        active: dev

    datasource: ...
```

**Update 2**

Ran into this issue again on newer version of Sprint Boot and had to change to this:

```
spring:
    http:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 30MB
            max-request-size: 30MB
```

Comment: See my edited answer; you need to configure `multipart.maxRequestSize` too

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In addition to configuring max file size, you may also need to configure max request size if you have a single file that's greater than 10MB or you want to upload multiple files in the same request with sizes that total more than 10MB.

The exact properties that need to be used depend on the version of Spring Boot that you are using as they [changed in 1.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#multipart-support):

#### Spring Boot 1.3.x and earlier

- `multipart.maxFileSize`
- `multipart.maxRequestSize`

#### Spring Boot 1.4.x and 1.5.x

- `spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize`
- `spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize`

#### Spring Boot 2.x

- `spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize`
- `spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Providing both maxFileSize and maxRequestSize will do the trick.

Comment: unnested it like this: multipart:
    maxFileSize: 100Mb
    maxRequestSize: 100Mb 
and it worked on my side :)

Comment: @christopher I've updated my answer to reflect the different properties used by different versions of Spring Boot

Comment: In spring boot 1.5, it changed again to be technologic specific https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#property-renames  , for example server.tomcat.max-http-post-size

Comment: In my case the only solution was to set `spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize` and `spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize` properties, because configuration was done by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartProperties`

Comment: for 2.0.0.RELEASE look to @Maksim answer

Answer (score 8):

for spring-boot 2.x, file: src/main/resources/application.yaml

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: -1
      max-request-size: -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Emilio Garcia mentioned, it has to be placed under `spring.http.multipart` and not `multipart` alone. I have recently upgraded a project from Spring Boot 1.3.5 to 1.4.1 and ran into the issue that `multipart.maxFileSize` is no longer honored .. it appears to have changed.

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/#_tuning_file_upload_limits), you need to use these properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
```

Comment: @Maksim answer is actually for current 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: Note, the unit of measurement supported are `B`, `KB`, `MB`, `GB`, and `TB`. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3’s default file size is 128000.

If You Want to increase the size go to application.yml of your project ,as i want to increase the size to 25 megabyte. the file size is set in bytes , as we see above max size is 128000 bytes. so i have to convert 25 mb into bytes.

25 mb * 1024 kb * 1024 b = 26.214.400 bytes

Now goo 
/grails-app/conf/application.yml

and write down these lines properly

grails:
 controllers:
  upload:
    maxFileSize: 26214400
    maxRequestSize: 26214400

Now clean the application and run again , it will work wonders. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding below to configuration worked for me:

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 20000
  ConnectTimeout: 20000
```

[Read Timeout on Request](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/321)

Answer (score 0):

For configuring CommonsMultipartResolver with external tomcat
Define a bean with bean name as **MultipartFilter.DEFAULT_MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME**
As the default spring boot's default MultipartFilter looks for resolver with default bean name.

```
@Bean(name = MultipartFilter.DEFAULT_MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
protected MultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);//size in bytes
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(20971520);//size in bytes
    return multipartResolver;
}
```