# "the request was rejected because its size " Spring, tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, upload

I'm trying to make a simple upload app with springboot and it works fine until i try to upload 10Mb+ files, i receive this message on my screen:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (14326061) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
```

I've done some research, and nothing have worked until now. I'll leave here below the things i've tried so far.

put this code(In various ways) in my "application.yml"

```
multipart: 
 maxFileSize: 51200KB
 maxRequestFile: 51200KB
```

I've also tried this in my principal class:

```
    @Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
     factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
         ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
        }
     });
     return factory;
}
```

And some strange thing. If i enter in my tomcat web.xml, the multipart-config is:

```
<multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

So where the hell this "...configured maximum (10485760)" is coming from ?
(Sidenote: I'm using netbeans 8.1 and springboot 1.5).

Thx guys.(And sorry for the english s2)

Since asked, this is my application.yml

```
 server:
      port: 9999
      context-path: /client
    logging:
      level:
        org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    endpoints:
      trace:
        sensitive: false

    spring:
        thymeleaf:
            cache: false
        multipart: 
          maxFileSize: 51200KB
          maxRequestFile: 51200KB  

    #################################################################################

    security:
      basic:
        enabled: false
      oauth2:
        client:
          client-id: acme2
          client-secret: acmesecret2
          access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
          user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
        resource:
          user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/me
    #
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572700/i-am-trying-to-set-maxfilesize-but-it-is-not-honored

Comment: try to use `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=51200KB` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=51200KB`

Comment: Thx for the replies. I've tried with "spring.servlet" but without success.
And i don't think it's duplicated since the solution in that question didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you please provide `application.yml` file

Comment: @Rahul Mahadik i've just added my application.yml.
Even within the "spring.http" this doesn't work...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
```

or

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

Reference [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Hope it will works

Comment: Thx, it worked (:
But how did you knew this,because it's not in the documentation, neither  in the other solutions to this problem. And why i had to enable it and other people didn't have too ?

Comment: @Estudeiro Welcome dude.   :)

Comment: @Estudeiro I'm working on Grails, which have also same configuration file. and i seen your exception `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase` so

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I'll comment here on the latest syntax for Spring 2.6.1: (Note the `http` -> `servlet`):

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```


As mentioned in the answer, for the latest version, it's best to refer to the [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Answer (score 8):

Following are the ways based on version,

1'st :

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB
```

2'nd :

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

3'rd :

```
multipart.enabled=true
multipart.max-file-size=100MB
multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Answer (score 3):

For SpringBoot 1.5.7 till 2.1.2 the property need to set in application.properties file are:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Also make sure you have application.properties file in "resources" folder.

Answer (score 2):

```yaml
spring:
  servlet: 
    multipart: 
       enabled: true 
       file-size-threshold: 200KB   
       max-file-size:       500MB 
       max-request-size:    500MB
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

In SpringBoot 2.6.3 setting "spring.http.multipart.max-file-size" did not work. Following did work for me:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
```

Answer (score 0):

For configuring CommonsMultipartResolver
Define a bean with bean name as **MultipartFilter.DEFAULT_MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME**
As the default spring boot's default MultipartFilter looks for resolver with default bean name.

```
@Bean(name = MultipartFilter.DEFAULT_MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
protected MultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(20971520);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I don't know why setting properties spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=20MB and spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=20MB in application.properties didn't work. To change max file size I've followed this guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded

So I've added this to my principal class:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver
      = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20000000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

and then, to handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException, I've copied this

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class FileUploadExceptionAdvice {
     
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleMaxSizeException(
      MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc, 
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) {
 
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("file");
        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", "File too large!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and wrote this simple file.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 th:text="${message}"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

After adding this code I've seen in logs that the MaxUploadSizeExceededException error was handled, but in browser I still got error. The solution was adding this to application.properties:

```
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=60MB
```

like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZMcg6LHC2k

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked in `application.properties` of  a Spring Boot 3 application (v3.0.5). This should be also the correct properties according to the [following guide / reference of spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) and as well here at the [source code documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartProperties.html) and the related Spring Boot [Multipart Auto Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartAutoConfiguration.html).

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128MB
```

I had **NOT** to add any special `@Bean`configuration. According to the [Multipart Auto Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartAutoConfiguration.html) documentation:

```
Auto-configuration for multipart uploads. Adds a
StandardServletMultipartResolver if none is present, and adds a 
multipartConfigElement if none is otherwise defined. The 
ServletWebServerApplicationContext will associate the 
MultipartConfigElement bean to any Servlet beans.
```

the following did **NOT** work (may be it worked in an earlier version of Spring boot).

```
#spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
#spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128MB
#spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128MB
```