# How to configure Multipart file size in application.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot

If I want to set the multipart file to take an infinite size of file to upload, how should I configure the application.yml file to set the same?

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at How to Ask and take the tour, if you have not done so already. Also take a look at minimal reproducible example. This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions. 
I would also strongly advise against allowing uploading an unlimited file size

Answer (score 0):

> In addition to configuring max file size, you may also need to configure max request size if you have a single file that's greater than 10MB or you want to upload multiple files in the same request with sizes that total more than 10MB.

The exact properties that need to be used depend on the version of Spring Boot that you are using as they [changed in 1.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#multipart-support):

It's already answered in [multi-part file size in applicaiton.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572700/i-am-trying-to-set-maxfilesize-but-it-is-not-honored.)